# keyboard events: Keyup give unconsistent behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with keyboard key-up events in Javascript (checked on chrome).

Presented below 4 parts are pleaced in four  different files, attach together. And it works quite fine but has one strange behaviour.

Look at the code and please **focus on marked line**:

MAIN.JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.onkeyup = function(event){
        EVENT_KEYBOARD(event);
    }
}
```

EVENTS:

```
function EVENT_KEYBOARD(event) {
    LOG_DEBUG("key pressed." + event.key + " code"+event.keyCode);
    main_controller.event_keyboard_click(event);
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
this.event_keyboard_click = function(event) {
    keyCode = event.keyCode;
    key = event.key;
    if(keyCode == 44){ myCanvas.abond_for_a_while(3000);}// PRINT SCREEN
    else if(keyCode == 27){ myConsolas.cursorEscape();} // ESCAPE
    ...
    else if(key == "Delete"){myConsolas.cursorDelete();}
    else {myConsolas.workForMe(event);}
}
```

CONSOLAS.JS :

```
this.workForMe = function(event) {
    key=event.key.toUpperCase();
// THIS LINE BELOW:
    if((key.length==1&&key>='0'&&key<='Z') || ",*-_ ;\'".includes(event.key)){
        ...
    }
}
```

And now lets consider four chars which are pleaced on two buttons on my (phisical) keyboard:

- key 1:   "0"  or ")"  when pressed with Shift
- key 2:   ";"  or ":"  when pressed with Shift

when i press **0** and **)** - then LOG_DEBUG prints:
 - *key pressed.0 code48*
 - *key pressed.) code48*

and when i press **;** and **:** then LOG_DEBUG prints:
 - *key pressed.; code186*
 - *key pressed.: code186*

Finally: condition

```
if((key.length==1&&key>='0'&&key<='Z') || ",*-_ ;\'".includes(event.key))
```

is TRUE for **: ; 0**
but is FALSE for **)** -- why? why? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns false for `)` because the range you are comparing against doesn't include that character, and you aren't checking for it in your list of extra characters (which also inlcudes some redundant characters). You have a lower bound of `'0'`, which is `48` and an upper bound of `Z`, which is `90`. That range includes the following characters: `0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

`)` has a character code of `41`.

```js
let chars = ''
let start = '0'.charCodeAt(0)
let end = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0)
console.log(`Starting at: ${start}`)
console.log(`Ending at: ${end}`)
for (let i = start; i <= end; i++)
{
  chars += String.fromCharCode(i)
}
console.log(chars)
console.log(`Value of ')': ${')'.charCodeAt(0)}`)
```